# no record found message in datatable,how?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datatable

i am using 'datatable jquery plugin' with server-side option to load table records.but i don't know how i can display a message like 'no data available' when no data return from mysql query.as i found the count of returned data which are in json format should be the same as column the table has.
i am working with php.

any help would be appreciated .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11193051/345659

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could hide the grid and show the message.

Markup:

```
<div id="noRecords" style="display:none"> There are no records </div>
<div id="dataTableContainer">
 ... (here goes your datatable)
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
if(count_of_returned_data == 0){
   $("#noRecords").show();
   $("#dataTableContainer").hide();
}else{
   $("#noRecords").hide();
   $("#dataTableContainer").show();
}
```

Hope this helps. Cheers