# How can I prevent the jquery dataTable plugin from adding row and message when there is no data

Tags: jquery, datatable

Our product owner would like the our empty tables to display just table header when there is no data in table. I can't seem to prevent dataTable from creating a row with "empty..." message.

Here is the code I use to initialize the dataTable. I know some things here are wrong. I have been experimenting. :)

```
$('#InBox').dataTable({
    "bFilter": false,
    "bPaginate": false,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "bInfo": false,
    "oLanguage": {
        "sEmptyTable": '',
        "sInfoEmpty": ''
    }
});
```

Here is some code I tried to put in the init function of the dataTable, but I am not sure how to get it to work.

```
/* Table is empty - create a row with an empty message in it */
            var anRows[0] = document.createElement('tr');

            if (typeof oSettings.asStripClasses[0] != 'undefined') {
                anRows[0].className = oSettings.asStripClasses[0];
            }

            var nTd = document.createElement('td');
            nTd.setAttribute('valign', "top");
            nTd.colSpan = oSettings.aoColumns.length;
            nTd.className = oSettings.oClasses.sRowEmpty;
            if (oSettings.fnRecordsTotal() > 0) {
                if (oSettings.oLanguage.sZeroFilterRecords.indexOf("_MAX_") != -1)
                    oSettings.oLanguage.sZeroFilterRecords = oSettings.oLanguage.sZeroFilterRecords.replace("_MAX_", oSettings.fnRecordsTotal());
                nTd.innerHTML = oSettings.oLanguage.sZeroFilterRecords;
            } else {
                nTd.innerHTML = oSettings.oLanguage.sZeroRecords;
            }

            anRows[iRowCount].appendChild(nTd);
```

Dan

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this

```
$('#InBox').dataTable({
  "bFilter": false,
   "bPaginate": false,
   "bLengthChange": false,
   "bInfo": false,
   "oLanguage": {
    "sEmptyTable": '',
    "sInfoEmpty": ''
   },
   "sEmptyTable": "There are no records",
 });
```

otherwise you can try this

```
$('#InBox').dataTable({
  "bFilter": false,
   "bPaginate": false,
   "bLengthChange": false,
   "bInfo": false,
   "oLanguage": {
    "sEmptyTable": '',
    "sInfoEmpty": ''
   }
 });
$('.dataTables_empty').html("No record found.");
```

Comment: My goal is to not show any message when the table is empty. I would prefer the row not be created. I have a button that adds rows to the dataTable. I will just need to add logic to remove the 'dataTables_empty' row before adding new rows. I used your code. I just set empty quotes so that their was no message. I will mark your answer as answer, if a more elegant way is not presented. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to remove the tbody attacched from datatable plugin, you can try this workaround:

```
$('.dataTables_empty').parent().parent().remove();
```

Answer (score 3):

Old post, but for the sake of people using search engines looking for the right answer here is how I accomplished.

Delete or comment out the following line from the dataTables source:

```
anRows[iRowCount].appendChild(nTd);
```

In the minified version, search and delete:

```
b[i].appendChild(c);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can customize DataTable plugin by using oLanguange:

```
"oLanguage": { "sZeroRecords": "-Put customized text-", "sEmptyTable": "-Put customized text-" }

And if you want to remove those, just put these components into null:
"oLanguage": { "sZeroRecords": '', "sEmptyTable": '' }
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

The most current way to hide the messages is by using the [language option](https://datatables.net/reference/option/language)

```
$('#loggedMessages').DataTable({
    "language": {
       "emptyTable": ' ',
       "zeroRecords": ' '
     }
 });
```