# checking datatables is has data

Tags: jquery, datatables

So i have datatables lets said name table is `reportpr`, and then i have jquery on these table (reload with ajax & json)
here my code :

```
var table = $('#reportpr');
        var target = table.attr('data-table');
        var tblDetail = table.attr('data-detail');
        var oTable = table.on( 'processing.dt', function ( e, settings, processing ){
            if (processing) {
                $(this).find('tbody').addClass('load1 csspinner');
            } else{
                $(this).find('tbody').removeClass('load1 csspinner');
            };
        }).DataTable({
            "bServerSide": true,
            "dom": 'Bfrtip',
            "buttons": [
                'excelHtml5'
            ],
            "scrollX": true,
            "scrollY":        "200px",
            "scrollCollapse": true,
            "iDisplayLength": 10,
            "ajax": {
                "url" : url+"datatable",
                "type": "POST",
                "data" :{
                           title: target
                        },
            }
        });
```

Well is work it showing my data, but my problem is how do i check these table if has data or empty (no data). 
I try so many thing on these option like `$("reportpr").DataTable().rows().count();`
OR `$("reportpr").DataTable().page.info();` but still not working, anyone any suggesting??? I just need check if my table has data or not.

EDIT :

I edit my question
I wanna make another even trigger, so not showing masaage on datatbles, like

```
if(datatable is empty)
{
 button it will enable
}
else
{
 button is will disabled
}
```

Update : I try update my version DataTables from version 1.10.5 into 1.10.16, and try using `$("reportpr").DataTable().data().any();` or `$("reportpr").DataTable().rows().count();`, is still not working, when that table has data is said i dont have data or empty data. Pls still help these thing.

Comment: Have you checked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11193051/how-can-i-prevent-the-jquery-datatable-plugin-from-adding-row-and-message-when-t

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent the jquery dataTable plugin from adding row and message when there is no data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11193051/how-can-i-prevent-the-jquery-datatable-plugin-from-adding-row-and-message-when-t)

Comment: That's not dupiclade, he just wanna make show empy on is datatable,and  i need check not showing a massage. That not duplicate, and the answer didnt help it out. Cause i need put on another event trigger.

Comment: @Wolfzmus Did you check [this documentation page](https://datatables.net/reference/api/count())? You can use that if you upgrade your plugin to 1.10.8+.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the simplest way is to count the rows - it will be 0 if empty:

`table.rows().count()`

Comment: See my question dude, i try that.

Comment: Ah, yep, I see your update. Are you using `$("reportpr").DataTable().rows().count();` as you said? If so, that's wrong, it should be `$("#reportpr").DataTable().rows().count();`

Comment: Akkh yes, i forgot add that thing `#`. Tq

Answer (score 2):

You Can use any() function to this.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

if ( ! table.data().any() ) {
    alert( 'Empty table' );
}
```

Comment: no working, it show error `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable(...).data(...).any is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:34`

Comment: What is the lib are you using for datatables ? "jquery.dataTables.js" or some thing else ?

Comment: im using jquery.dataTables.min.js, version 1.10.5

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`fnGetData`](https://legacy.datatables.net/ref#fnGetData) to determine if the table has data or not.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#maintable').dataTable();

  // Get the table's data.
  var data = table.fnGetData();
  
  // Check the data array length.
  if(data.length==0){
    console.log("Table is empty");
  }else{
    console.log("Table has "+data.length+ " rows.")
  }
});
```

```css
#tableWrapper{
  width:90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
table{
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.16/css/dataTables.jqueryui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<div id="tableWrapper">
  <table id="maintable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
          test1
        </th>
        <th>
          test2
        </th>
        <th>
          test3
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

In this [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/OvwPWJ?editors=1111) is the same example with 2 data rows.

Comment: no is not working. is diferent to get `fnGetData()` cause im using `bServerSide`.

Answer (score 0):

For server side, the best method is to use Datatable [drawCallBack](https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback) functionality as follows:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
        serverSide: true,            
        ajax: 'https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all',
     columns: [
          {
            data: ""
          },
          {
            data: ""
          }
     ],

    "drawCallback": function( settings ) {

        var rows = this.fnGetData();

        if (rows.length === 0 ) {

        }else{

        }    
    }
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

My app has an option to download CSV of the DataTable data. I was able to get the data length as shown below:

DataTable adds a class .**dataTables_empty** to the td when the data is empty
[image]

```
function downloadCSV = () => {
    var dataFound = false;
    if($('.my-table.dataTable').find('td.dataTables_empty').length == 0) {
       dataFound = true;
    }
    
    if(dataFound) {
        window.location.href = '/download-mytable';
    } else {
        toastr["error"]("No data available for download", "MyApp");
    }
}
```

Hope this helps if anyone searching solution using jQuery